# How to add index and query array within object in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Having multiple documents an structure similar to this:

```
{
'key1':value,
'key2':value2,
'galaxy':{
           'planets':['earth','mars','welcomebackpluto']
           'sun': 'something'
          }
}
```

I would like to query all the documents that have `mars` within the `planets` array in the `galaxy` object.

The indexes I've created haven't worked and I'm not able to query them, any idea how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array indexing

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON default (DISTINCT ARRAY (DISTINCT ARRAY p FOR p IN g.planets END) FOR g IN galaxy END) WHERE type = "xyz";

SELECT d.*
FROM default AS d
WHERE d.type = "xyz" AND ANY g IN d.galaxy SATISFIES (ANY p IN g.planets SATISFIES p = "mars" END) END;
```

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html